# ¿Por qué esta foto no se puede ver en la etiqueta imagen de html?

Tags: html5, imagen, cookies

Estoy intentando mostrar esta foto en una web, pero parece que algo bloquea para que se vea, puede que sean cookies lo que la bloquea.
¿Sabéis por que ocurre esto de que no se muestre la imagen?
¿Sabéis alguna solución para que se muestre sin tener que descargarla y subirla a otro servidor?

Os dejo el código HTML de la imagen que no se muestra y el de una imagen que si se muestra para que me digáis la diferencia.

```html
<!--no se muestra-->
<img width="300" src="https://img3.idealista.com/blur/WEB_DETAIL_TOP/0/id.pro.es.image.master/3b/f0/64/908436038.jpg">
<!--si se muestra-->
<img width="300" src="https://i.imgur.com/l49aYS3.jpg">
```

Comment: Se veen ambas amigo

Comment: Confirmo que las dos imágenes se ven correctamente.

Comment: si se ven solo que  la primera si que es un poco mas pesada y demora

Comment: vale es el navegador Google crome el que no me la muestra pero no entiendo el porque, la acabo de abrir con Edge y si que funciona, ¿por que me ocurre esto en google chrome

Comment: Estoy utilizando Google Chrome y puedo ver ambas fotos. En Firefox también puedo ver las fotos. También tengo la extensión adbloquer y puedo decir que no afecta en la visibilidad de las fotos al contrario de lo que decía otro comentario.

Comment: ya encontre el problema, era el bloqueador de publicidad

Comment: tendras otro bloqueador distinto al mio, yo uso adguard

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/298604)

Answer (score 0):

La foto no se muestra porque tengo en mi navegador google chrome instalado el bloqueador de publicidad "AdGuard adBloquer" y por alguna razón me bloquea la imagen

```html
<!--no se muestra-->
<img width="300" src="https://img3.idealista.com/blur/WEB_DETAIL_TOP/0/id.pro.es.image.master/3b/f0/64/908436038.jpg">
<!--si se muestra-->
<img width="300" src="https://i.imgur.com/l49aYS3.jpg">
```